# Contents of a file got erased

Tags: shell, pipe, io-redirection, sort, data-recovery

I used this command:

```
sort .file1 >.file2 | mv .file2 .file1
```

But then `.file1` is empty.

Why?
If my command is wrong how can I recover it?

Comment: use `;` or `&&` instead of the `|`....

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really make sense to have a pipeline in this case as the first part of the pipeline is not producing input for the second part, and the second part doesn't read anything from standard input.

Instead, just use

```
$ sort -o .file1 .file1
```

This will sort the file `.file1` "in place".

What happened when you ran your pipeline was that the shell created `.file2` as an empty file, and `mv` had time to replace `.file1` with this before `sort` managed to sort the contents of `.file1`.  All parts of a pipeline are started concurrently.

To recover, restore from backup.

Comment: Thank you. I am in Fedora. I didn't keep backup manually. Does fedora store backup by default? What can I do now? The file is very important. It contains valuable data.

Comment: I think the OP meant to use the `||` operator, not a pipeline.  BTW that would not have made sense either, a `&&` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal no, nothing does a backup of random files by default. That's why you must *always* have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `sort .file1 > .file2 && mv .file2 .file1`. with `|` pipe you just pass stdout of sort to `.file2` which was renamed to `.file1`
What kind of file-system do you have on this `/dev/sda1`, but be aware that recovery can be impossible